# how to find the angles given below.

Tags: geometry

what are the steps you need to find supplementary, complementary , opposite ,corresponding and alternate angle and also scalene triangle? I seriously need help with these angles and i have asked my teacher many times but.....lets just maybe someone here can help me understand it better.

Comment: Can you provide an example problem? It might help the community help you better since your question is too vague.

Answer (score 0):

Supplementary angles equal 180 degrees, so they make a straight line. Complementary angles equal 90 degrees, so they make a right angle. Opposite angles are across from each other. Alternate angles can be interior, which make a z shape, or exterior, which are opposite of the angles that make a z. Scalene triangles have all unequal sides and angles.

It might help to look up pictures of these.